# Is it possible to use SqlDataAdapter in a Client/Server scenario on the server side?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqldataadapter

**First of all:** we have an application that is build heavily around the legacy `DataTable` type. Because of this, we cannot switch to e. g. EF now. This will be a future project. In the meantime we need to build a new server-sided REST based solution as a replacement for the legacy server logics.

**Problem:** `SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataTable)` does not update the data in the database:

- New records: get inserted successfully in DB
- Modified records: above `Update()` method returns correct count, but the change is not in DB
- Deleted records: above `Update()` method returns 0 count and therefore throws concurrency exception (which is by design of the data adapter and not correct here)

**Supposed Cause:** As the `DataTable` is fetched by the server application on request of a client, but then transmitted to the client and back to the server before it gets written to the DB, `SqlDataAdapter` seems to not detect them properly as changes:

1. Client requests data
2. Server fetches data from database
3. Data is transmitted serialized via REST to the client
4. Client works on data
5. Changed data is transmitted serialized via REST to server
6. Server instantiates a new instance of `SqlDataAdapter` and makes `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` on this received data

**Data integrity:**

- the correct `RowState` of each record is present on the server side, when it makes the `SqlDataAdapter.Update()`
- the client transmits changed records only to the server, for efficiency reasons
- all of the tables have a `PK`
- none of the tables have `FK` relations (this is/was the legacy design rule)

Is it possible to somehow achieve (server-sided) `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` on "foreign" data or is this method designed for direct (client) updates to the database of the original data only?

**Common Errors:** of course I heavily searched for this issue already and took care of correct population of the sql command properties.

---

Server-sided code part:

```cs
public override int[] SaveDataTable(IEnumerable<DataTable> dataTables)
{
    var counts = new Queue<int>();
    using (_connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        _connection.Open();
        var transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            foreach (var table in dataTables)
            {
                //var command = new SqlCommand();
                var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
                using (command)
                {
                    command.Connection = _connection;
                    command.Transaction = transaction;
                    command.CommandText = Global.GetSelectStatement(table);
                    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    var cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                    dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
                    dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
                    //dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    //var dSet = new DataSet();
                    //dataAdapter.Fill(dSet);
                    //dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                    //dataAdapter.Fill(new DataTable());
                    //var clone = table.Copy();
                    //clone.AcceptChanges();
                    //dataAdapter.Fill(clone);
                    counts.Enqueue(dataAdapter.Update(table));
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transaction.Rollback(); //this may throw also
            throw;
        }
    }
    return counts.ToArray();
}
```

---

[image: RowState = Modified]

Comment: Yes, DbDataAdapter isn't a UI component, but it doesn't offer any benefits compared to more modern alternatives. It *does* update data, no matter where it runs. If you have problems with your code, post that code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how to achieve this then?

Comment: How to achieve *what*? What's the problem? Where's the code? Data adapters were used in ASP.NET WebForms to store changes in DataTables long before Entity Framework was introduced. They work, no matter where they run

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot deserialize RowState

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I try to achieve to store the changes of the modified records to the database. The problem is what I described after "Problem:"

Comment: @Selvin I checked in debugger on the server-side, that the `RowState` of the `DataRow`s was present

Comment: See the relevant code part in my updated question. The commented part were experiments that didn't alter anything.

Comment: RowState is calculated (it's only getter) so if you not use some low level serialization(which copy all the internal field) there is no way that you send RowState from client to the server

Comment: `It doesn't work` isn't a problem description. Unless you use a DataSet, the tables have no idea about related rows, so you can easily have invalid data. Since ADO.NET is so old, the way DataSets, DataTables and adapters work is thoroughly documented. When you have related data, the order of operations matters. You can't update all tables in a loop - master rows must be created first, detail rows must be deleted first.

Comment: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters) explain how they should be used, and [Ordering of Inserts, Updates, Deletes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters#ordering-of-inserts-updates-and-deletes) explains the order of the operations. If you use a typed dataset created using Visual Studio's designer, this code will be generated for you

Comment: DataTables work correct in my application. So you may have to post a reproducable example of your problem so we can investigate. We too are planning to rewrite our application and step away from DataTables, but never ever will we use EF. It simply is to slow for large databases. Consider using models and dapper, which is much more efficient.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos where do you mean that I wrote `It doesn't work`?? Are you reading a different question in parallel? :D

Comment: BTW data adapters are reusable. There's no reason to create them in a loop like this. If anything, you want to loop over the *adapters*, not the datatables, and call their operations in the proper order.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok thank you for the information of reusing the adapter

Comment: @Nicolas `does not update the data in the database:` is an `It doesn't work`. Without the code, it says nothing. Even with the code, there's still a lot missing - are there any relations? FKs? What are the tables? Is the database choking before you tried to save values that violate constraints? It's impossible to reproduce any problem just with this loop

Comment: @Nicolas *read* the docs. That's not how adapters are meant to be used. It's also unclear if there's *anything* to be saved. If the code called `AcceptChanges` before the loop for example, all rows will become `Unmodified`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank your for all your help, but it would help more if you don't would imply things that I didn't do. I read all the docs, I know the article you referred to, as I read it multiple times yesterday to find a mistake in my implementation. I know that it works when implemented plain directly on the client, as the examples show. Therefore, I am not asking how to do this in a straight-forward implementation. I am asking, if the client/server architecture with server-sided data fetches/updates is incompatible with this approach?

Comment: I updated the question with information about no table relations

Comment: `if the client/server architecture with server-sided data fetches/updates is incompatible with this approach` I answered in the very first comment that this was actually used for client/server from the very first .NET version. That's what people used for web applications for at least 8 years. That's what I used for web apps in 2006. And yes, it's a pain. Client/Server doesn't mean "web". If you use a desktop application to talk to a database you're still using client/server. The problem is the code. You have to isolate it.

Comment: To isolate the problem, create a new empty console app and add just enough code to reproduce the issue. On the other hand, if there are such problems using DataTables in a new application, you'll probably spend *less* time and encounter fewer problems if you start with EF. The real difference is that a DataTable is untyped and thus easier to use with arbitrary tables, while an ORM or typed datasets force you to use a specific schema

Comment: ok thank you for the clarification of the client/server approach. I will try to reproduce the problem in a minimal example. And yeah, believe me, I would send the DataTables to a far exile, if it wouldn't be a much bigger and mighty PITA to excise the DataTables from the legacy client implementation - because it is quite complex and totally relies on the DataTable as data management vehicle :(

Comment: `Deleted records: above Update() method returns 0 count and therefore throws concurrency exception` this will happen if there are *no* matching rows in the database, or if those rows have been modified by another connection. This means that the data has changed since it was loaded. That *is* a concurrency violation. Are you using a `rowversion` field for optimistic concurrency? This will change if eg a `Modified` field changes due to a trigger. Without such a field, all fields are used for concurrency checks

Answer (score 1):

ok, so the quest is solved. There was nothing wrong with the implementation of the `SqlDataAdapter` (except the improvement advises from the comments of course).

The problem was in the client application code in always calling `AcceptChanges()` to reduce the amount of data. Prior to sending changed data to the data access layer, the `RowState` of each rows were "restored" with `DataRow.SetModified()`, etc.

**This** causes the problem of `SqlDataAdapter.Update()`.

Of course this is logical, as the original `DataRowVersion` is lost then. But this wasn't easy to identify.